# If there is only one element added in to a linked list, are the head and tail pointing to that one element?

Tags: list, singly-linked-list

Or, is the head pointing to that one element and then the tail pointing to the null element that the one element is also pointing to?

Simple conceptual question. I'm learning Java but this probably pertains to other languages as well.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one element in a linked List, then the Head Should point to the starting address of the First Element (the only element in your case) & the tail should point to the starting address of the last element (in your case the first elements itself).

The tail should not point to NULL, rather the `next` part of the element should point to NULL indicating that it is a last element & the tail should actually point to the start address of the last element.

Answer (score 0):

The head and the tail are both pointing to the same element, so, when you want to add an element at the end of the list you can just do

```
tail.next = new Element ();
tail = tail.next;
```